# Nvim doesn´t introduce the correct symbols when I introduce symbols that require the "ALTGR" key

Tags: neovim

I dont know why but any time I try to input anything that requires the *"ALTGR"* key it introduces just the default key.
`Example: "# ~ @ |" -> "3 4 2 1"`
I´m using powershell and the windows terminal but when I use vim instead of nvim it seems to work perfectly.
Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.
It has to be with the Neovim version. I was using the 0.4 version but in the 0.5 it is already fixed.